# Are 'sweet' and 'mild' - Italian Sausage - the same thing?

Tags: meat, italian-cuisine, language, sausages

Do they refer to the same kind? Or is there a subtle difference?

And what essentially encapsulates the concept of a sausage being sweet? Is it typical sucrose driven sweetness inherent to the product...or the resultant chemical aftertaste on consuming it?

Cooking geeks unite! We have a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both *sweet* and *mild* refers to the sausages without hot red pepper flakes. The fact they are called *sweet Italian sausages* doesn't mean they contain sugar.

Comment: But there is still a difference between sweet and mild, because some companies sell both a mild version *and* a sweet version of Italian sausage.

Answer (score 2):

Sweet refers to the sweet basil that is not in the mild